# How to access Hive from Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I need to use spark to access both Hive managed tables and Hive external tables. After reading some Spark documents I got confused with how to do it.

In the Spark documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables), it says:

> Spark SQL also supports reading and writing data stored in Apache
> Hive.
> ......
> "When working with Hive, one must instantiate SparkSession with Hive
> support, including connectivity to a persistent Hive metastore,
> support for Hive serdes, and Hive user-defined functions."

Code example:

```
// warehouseLocation points to the default location for managed databases and tables
val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

In the Hive Warehouse Connector documentation (https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehouseconnector_for_handling_apache_spark_data.html) it said:

> You can use the Hive Warehouse Connector (HWC) API to access any type
> of table in the Hive catalog from Spark. When you use SparkSQL,
> standard Spark APIs access tables in the Spark catalog.

The question is, is the enableHiveSupport during initialization of the Spark Session enough to access Hive tables? In which case do I need to use Hive Warehouse Connector?

Comment: You able to solve this?